# Maintain DLL loaded even when process closed

Tags: delphi, dll

I'm developing a DLL file that will be loaded by my EXE... So the EXE will call the first DLL procedure and when this procedure get loaded I want to keep it openned even if the EXE get closed. The example is, I have a DLL with timer showing a 'Hello World' message.
DLL Code:

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls;

{$R *.res}

type
  TMyTimer = Class(TTimer)
  public
    procedure OnMyTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure DllMessage; export;
var
  MyTimer: TMyTimer;
begin
  MyTimer := TMyTimer.Create(nil);
  MyTimer.Interval := 10000;
  MyTimer.OnTimer := MyTimer.OnMyTimer;
end;


procedure TMyTimer.OnMyTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello World');
end;

exports DllMessage;

begin
end.
```

The EXE is loading like this:

```
procedure DllMessage; external 'Message.dll'

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DllMessage;
end;
```

When I close the EXE I want the DLL keep running and showing the message every 10 seconds... Is that possible?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, @Lloyd. That's an XY problem. The real question, which the accepted answer addresses, is about how to avoid the DLL contributing to long startup times. Keeping the DLL in memory was just one idea for how to achieve that (which didn't even work, anyway). Besides, *this* question isn't just about keeping it in memory, either, but about continuing to *execute*.

Comment: How did you make the timer work from within a DLL? Because a DLL doesn't have a message pump, which your timer relies on...

Comment: @user1526124:  You might get a more sympathetic response if you explain why the DllMessage routine needs to be in a DLL.

Comment: @Jerry The host pumps the queue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DLLs are loaded into processes and cannot exist without a process to host them. So what you ask is not possible.

If you want to close your process, but continue to execute code, you will need to start a new and separate process to execute that code.

Comment: @Jerry Accomplish what?

Comment: I've experienced issues where I'm unable to replace Indy DLL's because they're "In use by another process" although the calling process has ended.

Comment: libeay32 and ssleay32

Comment: @Jerry Use Process Explorer, for instance, to find out which process still has the DLL loaded. Remember that multiple processes can load DLLs.

Comment: @Jerry Also take a read of the error message that you quoted. "In use by another process."

Comment: One of the design goals of DLLs, in a time when memory was scarce, was that more than one process could use the same DLL code in memory. So if process A loads DLL X, and then process B starts and loads DLL X as well, Windows *can* (if some requirements are met) just map the already loaded DLL code to B address space. If A terminates, B is still using the DLL and the files thereby is still locked.

Comment: @Jerry:  If your DLLs are in the same directory as your Delphi program and that directory is not in the "PATH" environment variable, you're less likely to get such issues where another process has used your DLL. I find that with all the glitches and bugs in various versions of libeay32 and ssleay32 DLLs, I always should maintain a private copy of those DLLs in each folder where my Delphi EXEs are installed.

Answer (score 0):

u need Atach a A DLL to another process,
and hook ur code to execute on your processs !

this method is called Dll Injection and Code Hook, 
easy ways using madcodehook component

at
http://www.madshi.net/

example injection

http://help.madshi.net/DllInjecting.htm

example code hooking

http://help.madshi.net/ApiCodeHooking.htm

or
creanting ur ways

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces

Comment: Why is injection better than starting a new process? Also, u and ur are not words.

Comment: create new processes need new applications, you can use that are already running, use the system for example.
or it will always create a new process when starting.
Thus the DLL must be loaded into the system from the first run.

sorry for the translation of google!

Comment: What happens when those already running apps close? Injecting is something you do as a last resort. Starting a new process is trivially easy and normal.

Comment: I have to say -1 for an irrelevant opinionated solution, as well as your expression with `!`